# 9v battery voltage goes down very low when connected, but shoots back up when it is disconnected?

Tags: voltage, batteries, low-power, battery-operated, low-battery

Whenever I leave a 9v battery connected to my circuit (simple circuit connected to a motion sensor) It goes down to about 3.3v, but when I disconnect it again, it will slowly go back up to about 8v. why is that, and how do I fix it?

Comment: A \$9\:\text{V}\$ battery has about \$2\:\Omega\$ series resistance. You must be trying to pull way more than \$1\:\text{A}\$ (which will exhibit about \$3\:\Omega\$ series resistance if you try it) out of the battery, for it to drop so seriously low. They just aren't designed for that kind of load. Plus, they will heat up and the cells will separate due to the heat. They are for \$100\:\text{mA}\$ tops, as a general rule. So you find another battery type or change the load.

Answer (score 2):

This is the typical result of trying to draw too much current from a low capacity, high-impedance battery, and *especially so* near the end of their discharge life.

- The rectangular 9v "transistor radio" batteries are designed for relatively low currents.  You don't say how much your device draws, but it may simply be too much.
- You might have a low quality of even "fake" battery with much higher internal impedance than normal for this style.  This would especially be a likely suspect if you got it in a bulk package "deal" or online rather than in retail packaging from a major brand.  I once found a whole bulk box of what looked like major brand name AAA cells in an employer's supply closet all of which exhibited this kind of behavior in circuits where genuine ones worked fine.  Imagine if you will a 9v battery package containing 6 tiny button cells, rather than the usual 6 just-smaller-than-AAA cells.
- Your battery may be all but dead.

Generally speaking, questions about the usage of consumer electronics devices are off-topic here.  The allowed *engineering* form of this question would need to include an actual measurement of the current drawn by the load.

Comment: The device draws around 12v, but i don't need it to be that high so 9v is sufficient

Comment: Sorry, but that is incorrect.  12v is not a "draw" it is rather the voltage, if you will the "pressure" with which the battery is "pushing" (which in your case starts at 8v and quickly drops to 3 or so), what would be needed to analyze this in an engineering fashion would be a measure of the resulting current flow, for example from an ammeter connected in series with the battery and the load.  If you're not prepared to take that measurement, your options are 1) buy a new, quality battery or 2) decide the device is defective and get a better one.